# Sending real time audio from the field unit to the radio studio over 3G

Tags: radio

We have a temporary FM radio station running for a week before the May Day. We don't have a portable radio transmitter for our field reporter and we're planning on using the mobile data (3G) for the field to studio link.

Mobile data network here is quite good, but the latency varies. We can either use mobile phones/pads or the reporter can carry a laptop. Which protocol/software could be suitable for this kind of a scenario so that the audio stream survives a bit jittery and lossy network?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Pocket Lite or Pocket codecs](http://www.aeq.eu/products/groups/portable-devices), for example. They use [N/ACIP](http://www.ebu-acip.org/Main_Page) protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Expect a certain degree of latency. 3G (Such as hspda+) is fairly latent and not suited well for real-time data transmittal.